# Rails how to take all records that have a nil total_price out of array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I have:

```
    @taletids = Taletid.where(:online => true)
    @taletids.each{|taletid| taletid.calculate_total(params[:search])}
    @taletids.sort!
```

In my model I have:

```
    attr_accessor :total_price
    def <=> other
      self.total_price <=> other.total_price
    end

    def total_price
    @total_price = self.data
    else
    @total_price = nil
end
```

The problem is that I cannot sort objects that have a total_price of nil

Therefore I want to remove the total_price from the @taletids array if nil:

```
    @taletids = Taletid.where(:online => true)
    @taletids.each{|taletid| taletid.calculate_total(params[:search])}
        remove all the @Taletids that have total_price of nil
    @taletids.sort!
```

Comment: Your model code makes no sense starting at `def total_price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@taletids = @taletids.select{|taletid| taletid.total_price  != nil}
```

Comment: nitpicking: you usually write `something != nil` if `false` is a legit value of `something` (apparently not the case here). So maybe `@filtered_taletids = @taletids.select { |taletid| taletid.total_price }`. If you feel that using a explicit comparison is better, then you can write the more idiomatic: `@taletids.reject { |taletid| taletid.total_price.nil? }`. In any case (for the OP), use a different value name, now it has value 1 ... some magic... now it has value 2... don't do that.

Comment: `@taletids.select &:total_price` for pure Ruby, but it might make more sense to set the default to 0 rather than nil, then you don't have this problem.

Comment: @Joshua: yeah, the first case can now be reduced with the usual `&:method`. Typo: "different value name" -> "different variable name".

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
@taletids = @taletids.delete_if {|taletid| taletid.total_price == nil }
```

EDIT: Shortened it to use braces because it is a one-liner.

EDIT 2: So it doesn't delete the nils, only creates a new array without them in it.

```
@temptaletids = @taletids.delete_if do |taletid|
  taletid.total_price == nil
end
```

That implementation makes @temptaletids an array without any nils, but leaves @taletids alone.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Either way, with the two current attempts, it overwrites the @taletids array though, so the essentially do the same thing...If you wanted to save the nils, but only sort an array that doesn't have the nils, you could store it in a different array. Added that solution in my above answer.